# Connect to SQL Server with NestJs

Tags: node.js, sql-server, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to connect to SQL Server with Nest Js. I get this error:

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)  at Connection.tedious.once.err

I followed these steps

Installed TypeORM using

```
npm install --save @nestjs/typeorm typeorm mssql
```

Added database connection in `app.module.ts`

```
imports: [
     TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
       type: 'mssql',
       host: 'localhost',
       port: 1433,
       username: 'MYUSERNAME',
       password: 'MYPASSWORD',
       database: 'MYDATABASE',
       entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
     }),   ],
```

Enabled TCP/IP with port 1433 in SQL Server Network configuration.

I'm running SQL Server browser, SSMS.

But still I am getting connection error when running `npm run start` in nest js app. Could you please help me out how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you enabled/changed the TCP/IP configuration in SQL Server Configuration Manager > Server Protocols... did you remember to restart the SQL Service to apply the changes?

Comment: Yes.i restarted the sql services.but still getting the error

Comment: Have you enabled port 1433 for IPv4? If it's only enabled for IPv6 you may need to use `host: '::1',` instead of `host: 'localhost',` because on a dual-homed host localhost usually resolves to 127.0.0.1 (which is an IPv4 address).

Comment: Ya. It’s already set up like that. I restarted my system and created a new application. Now it’s connecting to sql server. Thanks all